# undeclared identifier using timestamp

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I get an undeclared identifier for 'day'. Not sure why.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Daily Box", overlay=true)

// Check if the current bar is the last bar of the day
lastBarOfDay = ta.change(time("D"))

// Check if the current time is between 5pm and 6pm    
startTime = timestamp(year, month, day, 17, 0)

endTime = timestamp(year, month, day, 18, 0)

rangeTime = startTime - endTime

inTimeRange = (time >= timestamp(year, month, day, 17, 0)) and (time < timestamp(year, month, day, 18, 0))

// Get the highest and lowest price during the time range    
highInTimeRange = ta.highest(high, rangeTime)
lowInTimeRange = ta.lowest(low, rangeTime)

// Draw the box if it's the last bar of the day and in the time range
if lastBarOfDay and inTimeRange
    box.new(bar_index, highInTimeRange, bar_index+1, lowInTimeRange, border_color=color.black, border_width=2, bgcolor=color.green)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript version 5, 'day' isn't a function.
You should use :

```
dayofmonth()
```

instead of 'day'